# Can I load iOS apps directly without jailbreaking devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Ok, first of all, I'm not trying to do anything illegal, I too am an iOS developper and I loathe those who steal our hard work. 
I want to know if there is a way to install a provisioning profile on an iOS device other than using apple's provisioning portal, or better yet, install one of my apps without a provisioning profile WITHOUT JAILBREAKING. The thing is, I developped a custom made app for a client, and they didn't bother to tell me beforehand, that it had to be installed on 50 devices. They need those devices ready next week, so there is no longer time to upload the app on the app store and, since apple has a 100 development devices per year policy, I can't upload all 50 of my client's devices to my provisioning portal. But also, he doesn't want me to jailbreak his devices.

So, what can I do? Am I just screwed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out ad-hoc distributions.

For example:

http://bluxte.net/musings/2009/05/17/ad-hoc-distribution-iphone-application

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html

Answer (score 6):

Best action for the short term: Charge your client $99 plus your time to set up an iOS dev account for the client, and put all the devices on that new account.  Create a new provisioning profile, and set up an ad hoc distribution for those 50 devices.

With an ad hoc distribution, the clients can download and install the app themselves from an http server, just like [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/).  We have a server set up for our clients where we send them an email with a link to the app on the web server, and when they click that link in Mail on their iOS device, the app is installed.  Clean.  Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can also suggest the company to purchase an enterprise account which has extra support for distribution of inhouse apps.

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/